# fengyuanchen/jquery-cropper Avoid creating new crop-box

Tags: jquery, cropper

I am using [jquery-cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/jquery-cropper) library for cropping images. The following is my current code.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="headShotImage" class="tl">
    <img id="image2" src="/Images/im.jpg">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
        var $image2 = $('#image2');

        $image2.cropper({
            autoCropArea: 0.5,
            strict: true,
            guides: false,
            highlight: false,
            dragCrop: true,
            cropBoxMovable: true,
            cropBoxResizable: false,
            mouseWheelZoom: true,
            minContainerWidth: 360,
            minContainerHeight: 270,
            minCropBoxWidth: 200,
            minCropBoxHeight: 200,
            minCanvasWidth: 360,
            minCanvasHeight: 270,
            touchDragZoom: true,
            crop: function (event) {
                console.log(event.detail.x);
                console.log(event.detail.y);
                console.log(event.detail.width);
                console.log(event.detail.height);
                console.log(event.detail.rotate);
                console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
                console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
            },
            ready: function () {

            }
        });
```

**CSS:**

```
    #headShotImage .cropper-crop-box {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    #headShotImage .cropper-view-box {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    #headShotImage .cropper-view-box {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #39f;
        outline: 0;
    }
```

This is working fine as shown below.

[image: Image1]

**Problem**

User can change the crop area size by clicking somewhere on the image and dragging(see image below). How do I prevent the user from creating a new crop area?

Note:
User should be able to move the crop box around.

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 2):

you can use following options ....

```
dragMode: 'move',
toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false
```